# Conditional formatting views in an Android listview : how to?

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, colors

I am a beginner in android kotlin. I wonder what could be the possibilities of formatting cards color in a listview according to some conditions (one condition per item set in an array).

I am thinking about making a custom listener. Is it the right method ?

What would you suggest ? (I would want to know the main steps to achieve this goal)

Comment: I think you mean a custom adapter not a listener ?

Comment: No I think about creating a custom listener for the card view and edit text. Is it possible ? My custom adapter is already set.

Comment: yes it's possible, do you want dynamic colors for card views that can be changed programmatically with on some conditions ?

Comment: Exactly I want this. And to be able to change many card at the same time.

Comment: you can use a listener implemented by fragment/activity, and then call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` in its callback.

Comment: Ok thank you. So making a custom listener is the right way. Good. If anyone can say how to make this custom listener it would be great. (Main steps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad ! It is very simple in fact: we can put formatting condition in the body of getView().
And then the format is applied automatically when data change.